# "Restricted in"

Tags: meaning

*"Product has been restricted in: list of countries"*

Does this mean the product is available only in the countries listed, or not available in them?

Thank you.

Comment: If a product is available only in certain countries, availability is *restricted **to*** those countries. We'd need more context to understand how a product can be *restricted **in*** a country (perhaps by only being available to those with a doctor's prescription, I don't know).

Comment: We will need more context to answer this question. The problem is knowing what is meant by *restricted*. When a product is *restricted* does it mean that it is completely unavailable? Or is *restricted* the alternative to being prohibited altogether?

Comment: It _should_ mean that in the listed countries, there are restrictions on availability (who may access / how much may be accessed / where it may be sold ...).

Answer (score 0):

It means that in those countries (in the countries listed),

the products will be **difficult to get hold of**.

The sort of restrictions that are applied (or may happen) are:
***shortages*** (the country may limit imports to encourage local production).
***inaccessibility:*** a medical certificate may be needed, or a police licence.
***cost:***  the product may be heavily taxed with import duty or sales tax.
***climate:***  some goods do not survive extremes of heat, cold, damp.

Shortage, limited access, high cost, poor durability  can all be called restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this mean the product is available only in the countries listed, or not available in them?

A direct answer, specific to its availability is: "Yes, it's available, but not everywhere, to everyone, freely". That's what "restricted **in**" means.

That said, is this product available freely in all other countries? - Yes (or that's what the message implies).